# Update a particular field based on some condition in a csv file

Tags: linux, csv

I am trying to update a csv file within a shell script to update a particular field based on some condition

1. The script will read the csv line by line.
2. Once it encounters "N" in f6 it will start calculating the new date for f3 and then substitute the old value with the new value.
3. Everything inside the script is fine and working as per expectation but when the csv is getting updated it is not getting the proper date in f3.
4. It is updating with some random values though it is calculating properly.

Code

```
    while IFS= read -r line;
        do
        echo $line
        Flag=`echo $line|cut -d, -f6`
        if [ $Flag == 'N' ]
         then
         freq=`echo $line|cut -d, -f4`        
        old_dt=`echo $line|cut -d, -f3`
        new_dt=`date -d "$yest_dt +$freq days" '+%Y-%m-%d'`
        echo $new_dt
        echo $old_dt
        sed -i "s/"$old_dt"/"$new_dt"/" $dir/abc.csv  
        sed -i "s/$Flag/"Y"/"  $dir/abc.csv    
        
           
        fi
        done < $dir/abc.csv  }

Log

    IFS=
    + read -r line
    + echo 123,server,2020-08-08,30,xyz@mail.com,N
    123,server,2020-08-08,30,xyz@mail.com,N
    ++ cut -d, -f6
    + Flag=N
     + '[' N == N ']'
    ++ cut -d, -f4
    + freq=30
    ++ cut -d, -f3
     + old_dt=2020-08-08
     ++ date -d '2020-07-13 +30 days' +%Y-%m-%d
     + new_dt=2020-08-12
     + echo 2020-08-12
     2020-08-12
     + echo 2020-08-08
     2020-08-08
     + sed -i s/2020-08-08/2020-08-12/ /dir/abc.csv
     + sed -i s/N/Y/ /dir/abc.csv
```

CSV output after the script runs

```
123 server  2020-08-12  30  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-10-11  90  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-10-11  90  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-09-11  60  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-08-27  45  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-10-11  30  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-09-11  60  xyz@mail.com    Y
123 server  2020-08-27  30  xyz@mail.com    Y
```

first 5 rows are as per expectation but 6th and 8th row contains wrong values, in the logs it is calculating correctly but not updating the sheet properly.

Comment: Good first question! I'd recommend including sample input data, you can probably reduce it to 3 lines of data, 1 before the required change, 1 where the change is required, and 1 after the required change should happen. Then update your Q to show the required output from those inputs. If this is going to be used to process large amounts of data, you might want to invest the time to learn about `awk` or `perl` as those languages can easily handle such problem without invoking any external processes (it will run much faster on big files). See [Awk Tutorial](http://gyrmoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) .

Comment: And if you must stick with a shell solution then add a tag for the shell you will be using. I'm hoping you're not working in a restricted environment that doesn't include an up-to-date version of `bash`. If you are using `bash` already, then join the 90's and use the "modern" form of `var=$(cmd-substitution)`. Such code is easier to post here on S.O. and you can easily nest substitutions when the needs arise. Good luck.

Comment: Oops, make that [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Thanks Shelter for your quick response, the first solution you suggested is already tested, I have already tested the code the way you mentioned and is working fine. Problem arose when tried with increased amount of data. And yes, am using bash.

Comment: "First solution"? I'm no longer clear what problem you are having. Have your worked your way thru [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`? (And check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section in the same link). Good luck.